# What is the best way to calculate how long is an object in a specific state?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I am looking for a recommended solution to solve problems like the one below.
Preferably with PostgreSQL, but any other SQL based solution would help.

So there is a table like this:

```
day        | object_id | property_01 | ...
2022-01-24 | object_01 | A | ...
2022-01-23 | object_01 | A | ...
2022-01-22 | object_01 | A | ...
2022-01-21 | object_01 | B | ...
2022-01-20 | object_01 | B | ...
2022-01-19 | object_01 | A | ...
2022-01-18 | object_01 | A | ...
2022-01-17 | object_01 | B | ...
2022-01-16 | object_01 | A | ...
```

The base table is a daily "backup", so normally there are no gaps in the line of days.
There will be always a row since the birth of an object till it is deleted from the main DB.

What I need is to tell is that if an object is in "A" state at the day of query, how long is this object in it.
In the example the right ansver is since 2022-01-22, so a simple MIN() does not give the right ansver.
Also I do not need to tell all of the intervals in the "A" state, just how long the current one keeps.

What I tried:
I. Select all the object_id's that are in "A" state at a given date.
II: Select all the rows based on the object_id's.

Now I am trying to make a recursive query, but if there is some better solution, it would be a great help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Best practice` is essentially a marketing term used by lazy authors or vendors trying to sell you something to follow blindly. Problems have solutions, with their advantages and disadvantages. When you see someone claiming something is a `best practice` *beware*

Comment: What you describe is a common enough problem that it has its own name `gaps and islands`. You're trying to identify islands of rows with the same status. Typically, this can be solved using windowing functions like `LEAD` and `LAG` to check whether the `previous` or `next` item in a set is still in the same `island`, eg `LAG(status) OVER (PARTITION BY object_id order by date)` will retrieve the "previous" status of an object_id by date. If it matches the current one, you're still in the island, if not, a new island has started.

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify a little bit. You mentioned that the right answer from your example is `2022-01-23`, should it be `2022-01-22`?

Comment: Thanks for all the help! It was the "gaps and islands" that led me to the solution.